# Populating data on UIlabel through from picker View

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm creating an app where I'm creating a list of Views using "for loop" and every view contains few label and pickerViews. when I click and select any value from the pickerView, my uilabel gets updated but as I clicked on any other pickerview and choose a different value from that, It gets updated to every previous label. So in this way only last picker value is showing in every UILabel.

I know the reason why it's happening because I have created that UILabel as property and accessing through "self". But If I don't access this way then how to update the value of that Label.

sample code:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *itemDict in self.returnItemsArray ) {
   self.issueLabel = [[TTTAttributedLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, shipmentY+3, 270, 20)];
            [_issueLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
            [_issueLabel setTextColor:LR_darkgray_color];
            [_issueLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]];
            [_issueLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
            [_issueLabel setTag:index];
            [_issueLabel setText:@"Size Change"];
            [returnOrderInfoView addSubview:_issueLabel];
}

-(void)picker:(LRPickerView *)picker closedWithSelectedIndex:(NSInteger)index{

  if (picker.type == SIZE_PICKER){
    [self.issueLabel setText:[[_sizeDictionary objectForKey:selectedVar]uppercaseString]];
}
}
```

Let me know if any other information needed.

Comment: You said "when I click and select any value from the UILabel gets update but as I clicked on any other pickerview and choose a different value from that, It gets updated to every previous label." That makes absolutely no sense whatsoever. I'd go so far as to call it "[**word salad**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_salad)".

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, all your labels have the same reference. To fix this problem, you’ll need a way of maintaining separate label references, like pointers in C.

I would suggest having an array of labels instead of only using `self.issueLabel`. A property would need to be added to your class such as:

```
@property NSMutableArray *issueLabels;
```

After you have initialized your label, add it to the array like so in your for loop:

```
[self.issueLabels addObject:issueLabel];
```

The indexes in the issueLabels array should then correspond to the indexes in `self.returnItemsArray`.

Then in `picker:closedWithSelectedIndex:`, the labels can be retrieved from the array using something like:

```
TTTAttributedLabel *issueLabel = ((TTTAttributedLabel *)self.issueLabels[index]);
```

and updated using

```
[issueLabel setText:[[_sizeDictionary objectForKey:selectedVar]uppercaseString]];
```